# How to fetch the columns of the synonyms for linked servers in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, query, synonyms

I am using two servers local (SQL Server running on my system) and remote (SQL Server running on another system). I have created synonyms in my local server for a table which is located on the remote server.

Synonym used- `CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[test] FOR remoteserver_name .[database_name].[schema_name].object_name`

**Requirement**

I need to fetch the columns of the synonym.

I can retrieve the columns of the synonym using below query in SQL server.

```
select * from dbo.test
```

**where**

`dbo` is synonym created schema name (local server schema name) and `test` is synonym name.

I have tried to retrieve the columns of the synonyms using below query, but I cannot fetch the columns

```
SELECT sys.schemas.name   AS SCHEMA_NAME,
       sys.synonyms.name  AS view_name,
       sys.columns.name   AS COL_NAME,
       sys.types.name     AS data_typename
FROM   sys.columns
       INNER JOIN sys.synonyms
            ON  OBJECT_ID(sys.synonyms.base_object_name) = sys.columns.object_id
       INNER JOIN sys.schemas
            ON  sys.schemas.schema_id = sys.synonyms.schema_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.types
            ON  sys.columns.system_type_id = sys.types.system_type_id
WHERE  sys.types.system_type_id = sys.types.user_type_id
       AND sys.schemas.name = N'scehmaname'
       AND sys.synonyms.name = N'synonymname'
```

Can you please suggest some other way to retrieve the columns of the synonym or correct the above query?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you are trying to achieve. Could you give us an example how you created a synonym on your server? ([Edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/212493/edit) your question and add the details) Then when you state that your are trying to get the same result by querying the `sys.xyz` tables, do you mean you would like to retrieve the defintions of your synonyms? Or just an overview of your synonyms? Thank you for putting in some additional effort into your question.

Comment: I have edited my question, can you please suggest solution for my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is that you ask your **local** server about the object from another, **remote** server.

`OBJECT_ID(sys.synonyms.base_object_name)` from your code will be resolved on a local server because `OBJECT_ID()` operates within local server, but you pass to it the name from remote server, so you'll get `NULL` here.

If you want to get remote object's `object_id`, you should do smth like this:

```
exec ('select object_id(''[remote_db].[remote_schema].[remote_table]'')') at [remote_server]
```

And in general, if you want to get the columns of remote object, you should execute your code on the `remote` server, looking for the columns of **remote** object in the **remote** `sys.columns` in the **remote** database, for example, this way:

```
declare @obj_name sysname = '[remote_server].[remote_db].[remote_table]';
declare @code nvarchar(4000) =
N'select c.name   AS COL_NAME,
       t.name     AS data_typename
from sys.columns c
     join sys.types t
        on c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
where c.object_id = object_id(@obj_name)';

declare @param_def nvarchar(400) = N'@obj_name sysname';

execute [remote_server].[remote_db].dbo.sp_executesql @code, @param_def, @obj_name = @obj_name;
```

**UPDATE 0**

> Scenario : I have server A which has two database( database1 and
>   (database2 ). I have created synonym in the database1. CREATE SYNONYM
>   [dbo].[synonym] FOR database2.[dbo].[objectname] How to write query
>   commonly to get object_id for this scenario and remote object ?

As Scott Hodgin mentioned, you can use `PARSENAME()` to get rid of remote_server's part of your object like this:

```
declare @cmd varchar(8000) = (select 
       'select object_id(' + 
       quotename (
       PARSENAME(base_object_name,3)  + '.' + 
       PARSENAME(base_object_name,2)  + '.' + 
       PARSENAME(base_object_name,1), '''')+ ')'
from sys.synonyms )

exec (@cmd) at [server_A];
```

**UPDATE 1**

> I want to know whether I can access the stored procedure of the remote
>   server(Server B) from local server(Server A).
>
> ...
>
> I cannot get the list of the stored procedure.

You can get the list of remote stored procedures using this code:

```
select *
from remote_server.remote_db.sys.objects
where type = 'p';
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, its working fine.

  May I know how to get object_Id for below mentioned scenario

  Scenario : 

  I have server A which has two database( database1 and (database2 ). I have created synonym in the database1.
  
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[synonym] FOR database2.[dbo].[objectname]


 How to write query commonly to get object_id for this scenario and remote object ?
 
Kindly suggest me query.

Comment: @Subaashini Pushparaju I updated my answer with the new code for object_id()

Comment: Thanks. I have one more requirement in the synonym. Kindly suggest some ways or query to solve this.

  I need solution for two scenarios. Consider Server A(local server) and Server B(remote server). 

  Scenario 1 - I have created synonym in the server A for stored procedure in the server B. 
  Scenario 2 - I have create synonym in the server A for stored procedure in the server A.

  I cannot retrieve the columns of the synonym stored procedure.

Comment: @Subaashini Pushparaju, sorry, what do you mean saying "columns of the synonym stored procedure", stored procedures do not have columns, do you mean something else?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my requirement wrongly. I want to know whether I can access the stored procedure of the remote server(Server B) from local server(Server A).
I have linked two servers, Server A and Server B.  I tried to access the stored procedure of the server B in the Server A.
I cannot access it so can please conform whether I can access the stored procedure.

Comment: @Subaashini Pushparaju You may need to turn on RPC OUT on your linked server. Rigth click on your lonked server, open Properties, turn on RPC OUT

Comment: RPC OUT value is True only, but I cannot get the list of the stored procedure. Whether I need to enable any option in the remote server.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "I tried to access the stored procedure of the server B in the Server A. I cannot access it", I understood that you could not execute remote proc on the local server. So you want to get a list of remote stored procedures? But what have synonyms to do with this list?

Comment: @Subaashini Pushparaju If you just want to get a list of remote stored procedures,  the answer is updated with the code to do this. If it returns no rows but you know that there are procedures this can mean that you have no permissions on those procedures

Comment: Thanks, I need to access the stored procedure. You asked to check RPC OUT so I have updated the value in the comment.

Comment: RPC OUT needs to be turned on on a linked server if you want to be able to EXECUTE remote stored procedure calling it on local server

Comment: I am getting null value as result while fetching columns of the synonyms using this code.
"declare obj_name sysname = '[remote_server].[remote_db].[remote_table]';
declare code nvarchar(4000) =
N'select c.name   AS COL_NAME,
       t.name     AS data_typename
from sys.columns c
     join sys.types t
        on c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
where c.object_id = object_id(obj_name)'"

Comment: How do you execute this code? You wrote only variable declaration

Answer (score 3):

I upvoted [sepupic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/124448/sepupic)'s answer.

This is another example of how you could do this - it may need to be adjusted per your requirements.

I'm using dynamic SQL and [sp_columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

In my example, I created a synonym called `syntest` as follows:

```
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[SynTest] FOR [SqlCompare].[SCOPERATIONAL_DBCC].[SCFBDM].[CFG_LINE_BUS]
```

This synonym points to server `SqlCompare`, database `SCOPERATIONAL_DBCC`, schema `SCFBDM` and table `CFG_LINE_BUS`.

Issuing `select * from sys.synonyms where name = 'syntest'` reveals a base_object_name of `[SqlCompare].[SCOPERATIONAL_DBCC].[SCFBDM].[CFG_LINE_BUS]`.  I can use [PARSENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to extract the individual parts of the base_object_name to build the dynamic SQL statement

```
Declare @Cmd nvarchar(4000)

select @Cmd = 
    'exec ' + PARSENAME(base_object_name,4) + '.' + 
    PARSENAME(base_object_name,3) + 
    '.dbo.sp_columns @table_name = ' + '''' + 
    PARSENAME(base_object_name,1) + 
    ''',@table_owner = ' + 
    '''' +  PARSENAME(base_object_name,2) + ''''
    from sys.synonyms where name = 'syntest'    --<<<< The name of your synonym
PRINT @CMD
exec sp_executesql @cmd
```

The `PRINT` statement shows the built dynamic SQL as

`exec SqlCompare.SCOPERATIONAL_DBCC.dbo.sp_columns @table_name = 'CFG_LINE_BUS',@table_owner = 'SCFBDM'`