# How to join sys.columns and sys.synonyms table using object_id column

Tags: sql-server, query, metadata, synonyms

I have used two servers, Server A(local server) and Server B(remote server).
I have created synonyms in the Server A for the Server B table. I have created  synonym using following syntax.

```
CREATE SYNONYM RemoteServerATable FOR Server B .[database_name].[schema_name].object_name
```

I have tried to join two tables sys.columns and sys.synonyms using below query

```
select s.name as [SynonymName], c.name as [ColumnName], c.object_id from [Server B].[DatabaseName].sys.columns c inner join sys.synonyms s on s.name = 'RemoteServerATable' and  c.object_id  = 1973582069
```

I have joined two tables using object_id of the sys.columns tables in the other server and hard coded integer value. I got this value using below query

```
exec ('select object_id(''[Server B DatabaseName].[Server B SchemaName].[Server B ObjectName]'') as object_id') at [Server B]
```

I am not getting correct columns information. Kindly suggest someways join two tables and get the column information.

Answer (score 2):

`object_id()` does not work for remote databases.

[The documentation states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> For objects that are not found in the sys.objects catalog view, obtain
>   the object identification numbers by querying the appropriate catalog
>   view

SQL that provides an answer to your query requirement is [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/212493/how-to-fetch-the-columns-of-the-synonyms-for-linked-servers-in-sql-server).